Semigroup property in Markov processes
I am reading "The Theory of Open Quantum Systems, by Petruccione and Breuer." My questions are from the section 1.4 (Markov processes) and 3.2 (quantum Markov processes).
Here are some equations and notations:
(from part 1.4)
$T(x,t|x',t')$ is the conditional transition probability (density), simply called as the propagator, which is "the probability density that the stochastic process takes on the value x at time t under the condition that the process took the value x' at some prior time t' ". It has the following properties:
$$ 
\int dx T(x,t|x',t') = 1 \\
lim_{t \to t'} T(x,t|x',t') = \delta(x-x')$$
The Chapman- Kolmogorov equation is:
$$ T(x_3,t_3|x_1,t_1) = \int dx_2 T(x_3,t_3|x_2,t_2) T(x_2,t_2|x_1,t_1)$$
For a homogeneous Markov process, where we write the propagator as $T_\tau (x|x')$ (with $\tau= t-t'$), it becomes:
$$
T_{\tau+\tau'}(x|x') = \int dx_2 T_\tau(x|x_2)T_{\tau'}(x_2|x'), \quad     \tau, \tau' \geq 0.
$$

My Questions:

It has mentioned that the one-parameter family {$T_\tau|\tau \geq 0$ } represent a dynamical semigroup.

What is the binary operation in this semigroup? If we consider the set {$T_\tau|\tau \geq 0$ }, is the binary operation:
$$  T_\tau \times T_{\tau'}   \to T_{\tau +\tau'},$$
defined as the  Chapman- Kolmogorov equation given above. But then what about $x$ and $x'$?

Just to be sure, do non-homogeneous Markov processes have the semigroup property?

In section 3.2, if we define the superoperator responsible for evolution of our open system's density matrix as: $ \rho_S (t)=V(t)\rho_S (0)$, it is mentioned that as in classical theory, for the homogeneous Markovian-type behavior, the semigroup property is:
$$V(t_1)V(t_2)=V(t_1+t_2), \quad t_1,t_2 \geq 0.$$


What I don't get is how we are allowed to do this generalization to open quantum systems.

Binary operation in semigroups
In a semigroup,the binary operation is about combining two operators to get new one. So, if you have operators $T_\tau$ and $T_{\tau'}$, which describe how evolution over times $\tau$ and $\tau'$, their combination should give you a new operator that describes evolution over the combined time $\tau + \tau'$.
It’s better to see it as composing the operators. If you start with a state $x'$ and want to know where it ends after time $\tau + \tau'$, you first evolve it for time $\tau$ and then for time $\tau'$. We write this as:
$$(T_\tau \circ T_{\tau'})(x|x') = T_{\tau+\tau'}(x|x')$$
to show that the composition rule is satisfied,we use the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation:
$$
T_{\tau + \tau'}(x|x') = \int dx'' \, T_\tau(x|x'') T_{\tau'}(x''|x').
$$
This equation tells us that the propagator for the total time $ \tau + \tau' $ is obtained by composing the propagators for times $ \tau $ and $ \tau' $ Thus:
$$
(T_\tau \circ T_{\tau'})(x|x') = \int dx'' \, T_\tau(x|x'') T_{\tau'}(x''|x'),
$$
which equals $ T_{\tau + \tau'}(x|x') $. Then, the composition of two propagators gives a new propagator, confirming the binary operation is well-defined.
Role of $x$ and $x'$ in propagators
In this context, $x$ and $x'$ are just labels for the states of a system at different times.$x'$ represents the state at the initial time, and $x$ represents the state at a later time. The propagator $T_\tau(x|x')$ tells us the probability density for the system to move from state $x'$ to state $x$ over a time interval $\tau$.
If you start with an initial probability density function $\rho(x')$, the propagator $T_\tau$ helps you figure out how this density evolves over time $\tau$.  $T_\tau$ acts like a tool that transforms the initial density $\rho(x')$ into the evolved one $\rho(x)$.
So,although $x$ and $x'$ represent specific states, what is important for the semigroup property is how the operators $T_\tau$ combine through composition. This composition results in a new propagator $T_{\tau + \tau'}$, keeping the semigroup properties.
Non-homogeneous Markov processes
Non-homogeneous Markov processes are a bit trickier. Here, the transition probabilities depend on absolute times, not just the time differences. So, you can not always combine operators in a straightforward way, instead, you use time-ordered products. The Chapman-Kolmogorov equation still works, but it’s adapted for multiple different times:
$$
T(x_3, t_3 | x_1, t_1) = \int dx_2 \, T(x_3, t_3 | x_2, t_2) T(x_2, t_2 | x_1, t_1).
$$
This tells you how to break down the transition from time $t_1$ to $t_3$ into intermediate steps, but it doesn’t simplify into a semigroup form. This is because the propagators depend on the specific times $t_1, t_2, t_3$, rather than just their differences.
Generalization to open quantum systems
When we move to open quantum systems, the idea of the Markov property still holds true, and it leads to the semigroup property. For open quantum systems, the evolution of the density matrix is handled by a superoperator. This superoperator is like a quantum version of the classical propagator, mapping the initial density matrix to the final one over time. The semigroup property applies here as well, allowing us to break down the evolution into successive transitions, similar to what we do in classical systems.
The Markovian approximation in quantum systems is often justified when the coupling between the system and its environment is weak, and the environment correlation time is much shorter than the characteristic time of the system's evolution.
For many real quantum systems, especially those with strong system-environment coupling or structured environments, non-Markovian approaches may be necessary.
